# Can't create a new node project

Tags: node.js, npm

Hello so i have been trying all day to create a new node project, but there's no way,i receive this error:

[the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcF27.png)

i desinstalled and reinstalled node js,but the problem still persist, everything was working today morning.Please help,am stuck apparently i am the only one who got this error,i searched eveywhere on the web but no one had the same problem as me .

```
> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'create-jjj@latest',
1 verbose cli   '--global',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\tokis\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\6432',
1 verbose cli   '--loglevel',
1 verbose cli   'error',
1 verbose cli   '--json'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.16.0
4 verbose npm-session 99f9bbdb8eb57274
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-jjj 2932ms
8 http fetch GET 404 https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-jjj 346ms
9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for create-jjj@latest 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-jjj - Not Found
10 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
11 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 4012ms
12 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-jjj - Not Found
12 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:117:15
12 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
13 verbose statusCode 404
14 verbose pkgid create-jjj@latest
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\tokis\Desktop\Nouveau dossier
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "create-jjj@latest" "--global" "--prefix" "C:\\Users\\tokis\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_npx\\6432" "--loglevel" "error" "--json"
18 verbose node v14.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code E404
21 error 404 Not Found - GET https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp/create-jjj - Not Found
22 error 404
23 error 404 'create-jjj@latest' is not in the npm registry.
24 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
25 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
26 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
27 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```